# Set up alternating section colors with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

As opposed to using a table, I have structured sections which at one time were divs. I'm wondering if there is a way to alternate row colors dynamically between each section that is displayed:

```
<div>
  <name-section></name-section> (blue)
  <address-section></address-section> (green)
  <city-section></city-section> (blue)
  <postal-section></postal-section> (green)
</div>
```

etc.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? And then could do something like this: http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: Are you wanting a directive that alternates row colors of children in a div or are you wanting the tags you have outlined to always have the color you mentioned above?

Comment: I could add the sections into a div element so that the children were alternated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/5AWNm/1/).  This uses css to do it.

```
div > *:nth-child(even) {background: green}
div > *:nth-child(odd) {background: blue}
```

Comment: So close! I just realized part of the problem is that my sections are not rendered to the browser since they don't technically exist (name-section, address-section, etc.)